# Way to dim outside windows / Turn the lights feature

Tags: windows-7, windows, shell

I am looking for a way to replicate the "Dim out" or "Turn the lights off" feature (that can be seen on various video sites on the web) into Windows ? This will darken (dim out) the active window.
It could be a windows shell extension/plugin or a video player plugin that has this feature.

The reason for I am looking for this is that I  have a rather large monitor and doesn't use the whole screen when watching movies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kino](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2010/05/kino-masks-your-screen-for-customised-distraction-blocking/) is probably the slickest.

Comment: Thank you.. Found out that there is a couple of alternatives to: http://alternativeto.net/software/cinemadrape/